# change date-attribute value after selecting element with equal class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the value date of each element, but in the end of the loop all elements are given the same attribute = /

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koez1mt1/)

```
var el = $(".div-parent").find(".div-children");
 $(el).each(function( index ) {
    el.attr('data-attr',parseInt(el.attr('data-attr'))+1);
 }); 
 $(el).each(function( index ) {
     $(".div-parent").append('<br/>elemment '+el.attr('data-attr'));
 });
```

output:

```
elemment 1
elemment 2
elemment 3

elemment 4
elemment 4
elemment 4
```

desired output:

```
elemment 1
elemment 2
elemment 3

elemment 2
elemment 3
elemment 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the jQuery in your fiddle, it sounds like you want:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1093m1ob/)

```
$(".div-parent .div-children").each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('data-attr', parseInt($(this).attr('data-attr'), 10) + 1);
  $(".div-parent").append('<br/>elemment ' + $(this).attr('data-attr'));
});
```

The problem was that you were getting the `data-attr` attribute of the first element in the jQuery object each time. In other words, `1` was being incremented 3 times (since you looped over the elements 3 times), resulting in 4. Access the attribute of the current element on each iteration by accessing `this`.

As a since note, you should probably specify a `radix` value in the `parseInt` function. In this case, `10`.

Comment: uooww very nice! tkss @josh-crozier

Answer (score 1):

Using `clone()`. I prefer this approach since using this gets you the entire object and then you can change its attribute as needed.

```
var el = $(".div-parent").find(".div-children");
$(".div-parent").append("<br/>");
 $(el).each(function( index ) {
  var el_new = $(this).clone();  
    el_new.attr('data-attr',parseInt($(this).attr('data-attr')) + 1);
  el_new.text("elemment " + (parseInt($(this).attr('data-attr')) + 1));
  $(".div-parent").append(el_new);
 });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/koez1mt1/3/

Comment: I will accept the first answer for answering me faster, anyway thank you!

Comment: no worries. just wanted to make sure aware of doing things differently :)